# Javascript not working in Pushed Page of ons-page Onsen UI

Tags: javascript, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm using Cordova/PhoneGap and Onsen UI. I have two html pages. Switch(pushpage) button is working perfect. But Javascript not working in search.html

Here is my code:

- index.html (Default Main Page)
- search.html

**index.html**

```
...
<body>

<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
<ons-button
        onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('search.html', { animation: 'lift' })">
        Switch Page
</ons-button>
</ons-navigator>
</body>
```

**search.html**

```
<ons-page>
<script>
alert('Testing Javascript');
</script>
</ons-page>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `search.html` page is inserted dynamically when `myNavigator.pushPage('search.html')` is called.

When a `<script>` tag is inserted in this way the code is not executed.

Please refer to this question for more info:
[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

In order to execute some script when a page is pushed you can use the `postpush` event:

```
ons.ready(function() {
  myNavigator.on('postpush', function() {
    alert('Hello, world!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you put all the JavaScript in js files and call the function when you click the button, for example:

*HTML*

```html
<body>
  <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
    <ons-button
        onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('search.html', { animation: 'lift' }); callAlert();">
        Switch Page
    </ons-button>
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
```

*JS*

```js
function callAlert() {
  alert('Testing Javascript');
};
```

Alternatively, you can use `ons-navigator` events, like `postpush`, to personalize your code even more, you can take a look at them [HERE](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html)